# Html images not showing up because of minification

Tags: html, image, gruntjs, minify

I'm building a web application with AngularJS, the application was generated using Yeoman and I'm using Grunt for some tasks as minification, testing, etc. 
The problem I'm facing is related to the minification of the images, actually I want to display a simple image in html, so I use:

```
<img alt="" src="app/images/Next-SS12.jpg">
```

The problem is that after the minification of the image performed by Grunt, the name of the image has been changed to: 6e5c3c3f.Next-SS12.jpg , however the name of the image in the html has not been updated and remains the same. So here is the conflict because when I deploy the app , the image is not shown. I'm not against minification of the images but if the link that references the image is not updated, images will never be displayed.

Does someone know a way to fix that??

Thank you very much in advance.

My whole Grunt file:

```
// Generated on 2014-09-17 using generator-webapp 0.4.9
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Configurable paths
var config = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    config: config,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['bowerInstall']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        jstest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['test:watch']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        sass: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['sass:server', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
            ]
        }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            open: true,
            livereload: 35729,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                        connect.static(config.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                open: false,
                port: 9001,
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect.static('test'),
                        connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                        connect.static(config.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                livereload: false
            }
        }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },

    karma: {
        unit: {
            configFile: 'karma.config.js'
          }
        },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
//        jshint: {
//            options: {
//                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
//                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
//            },
//            all: [
//                'Gruntfile.js',
//                '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
//                '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
//                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
//            ]
//        },

    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
//        mocha: {
//            all: {
//                options: {
//                    run: true,
//                    urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%=          connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
//                }
//            }
//        },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    sass: {
        options: {
            includePaths: [
                'bower_components'
            ]
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                src: ['*.scss'],
                dest: '.tmp/styles',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        },
        server: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                src: ['*.scss'],
                dest: '.tmp/styles',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    bowerInstall: {
        app: {
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
            exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap-sass-  official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js']
        },
        sass: {
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}']
        }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
        },
        html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                src: '{,*/}*.html',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //                 '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //                 '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //     dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'partials/**/*',
                    'WEB-INF/**/*',
                    'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                    '{,*/}*.html',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }, {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '.',
                src: ['bower_components/bootstrap-sass-  official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*.*'],
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'sass:server',
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'sass',
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:test',
            'autoprefixer',
            'karma'
        ]);
    }




});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
   // 'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
};
```

Comment: First of all, which grunt plugins you use? Only uglify will not change file names by default. Btw: I would not recommend to minify images at all, since they are already efficiently compressed.

Comment: I just edited the question with the code of my Grunt file. I'm using uglify apparently, but it is changing the name of the image anyway, how can specifiy to not change the name , or how can I disable the minification of the images?

Comment: Can you upload the whole gruntfile?

Comment: Done. Uploaded my whole Grunt File.

Comment: I found undesired image renaming. It is in the task "rev". Just remove the line "'<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*'," (217).

Comment: Wow! That was it!! Thank you very much! If you want to post this as answer I'll accept it as accepted answer. Again Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grunt task "Rev" renames your image file (to avoid browser caching, ..):

Just remove the following line to disable image revisioning:

```
'<%= config.dist %>/images/{,/}.*',
```